# Why isn't component being updated through useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I can't see `<PostWidget/>` in the UI for below code.

**PostsWidget.jsx**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setPosts } from "../../../Redux/Slices/authSlice";
import PostWidget from "../PostWidget";
import { userRequest } from "../../../requestMethod";

const PostsWidget = ({ userId, isProfile = false }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  console.log("posts", posts);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    const res = await userRequest.get("/posts");
    console.log("all Posts", res.data);
    dispatch(setPosts(res.data));
  };

  const getUserPosts = async () => {
    const res = await userRequest.get(`/${userId}/posts`);
    console.log("user Post", res.data);
    dispatch(setPosts(res.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isProfile) {
      getUserPosts();
    } else {
      getPosts();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {posts && posts.map(
        ({
          _id,
          userId,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          description,
          location,
          picturePath,
          userPicturePath,
          likes,
          comments,
        }) => (
          <PostWidget
            key={_id}
            postId={_id}
            postUserId={userId}
            name={`${firstName} ${lastName}`}
            description={description}
            location={location}
            picturePath={picturePath}
            userPicturePath={userPicturePath}
            likes={likes}
            comments={comments}
          />
        )
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PostsWidget;
```

**PostWidget.jsx**

```
const PostWidget = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Post Widget</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostWidget;
```

Here,
**userRequest** is an axios method. I wrote two functions **getPosts** and **getUserPosts** to call the API

**AuthSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
  mode: "light",
  user: null,
  token: null,
  posts: [],
};      
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {                 
 setPosts: (state, action) => {
      state.posts = action.payload.posts;
    },
    setPost: (state, action) => {
      const updatedPosts = state.posts.map((post) => {
        if (post._id ===action.payload.post._id) {
          return action.payload.post;
        }
        return post;
      });
      state.posts = updatedPosts;
    },
  },
});
```

I checked the console.logs and also redux state with the `redux devtool`. Both are showing upadated `posts`.
**console.log**

> all Posts (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Comment: Is there a chance your update of posts state is not done in immutable way (and thus no state change is detected and consequent re-render does not happen)?

Comment: import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  mode: "light",
  user: null,
  token: null,
  posts: [],
};      
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {setPosts: (state, action) => {
      state.posts = action.payload.posts;
    },
    setPost: (state, action) => {
      const updatedPosts = state.posts.map((post) => {
        if (post._id === action.payload.post._id) {
          return action.payload.post;
        }
        return post;
      });
      state.posts = updatedPosts;
    },
  },
});

Comment: Edited the post. Please check how the states are being updated through redux.

Comment: What is the value of `res.data` in both cases? Is there a `res.data.posts` value? In other words, what is the value of `action.payload.posts` in the reducer function?

Comment: `res.data` is an array of `posts`.  Since `res.data` is an array of `posts`, there will be no chaining like `res.data.posts`

Comment: Hi, think you showed me the way. putting `dispatch(setPosts({ posts: res.data }));` resolved the issue. The thing that still surprises me why it didn't show me any error and the state was still being updated in redux-dev-tool. I literraly can't chain an array, but still it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is updating the `state.posts` in wrong way. Since  `setPosts: (state, action) => { state.posts = action.payload.posts; },` Need to update the code as follows:

**PostsWidget.jsx**

```
  const getPosts = async () => {
    const res = await userRequest.get("/posts");
    console.log("all Posts", res.data);
    dispatch(setPosts({ posts: res.data }));
  };

  const getUserPosts = async () => {
    const res = await userRequest.get(`/${userId}/posts`);
    console.log("user Post", res.data);
    dispatch(setPosts({ posts: res.data }));
  };
```